# How can we set the execution parameters for an apache spark application

Tags: apache-spark

We have setup a multinode cluster for testing the Spark application with 4 nodes.
Each node has 250GB RAM,48 cores.
Running master on one node and 3 as slaves.

And we have developed a spark application using scala.
We use the spark-submit option to run the job.
Now here is the point we are struck and need more clarifications to proceed.

Query 1: 
Which is the best option to run a spark job.
a) Spark as master
b) Yarn as master
and the difference.

Query 2:
While running any spark job we can provide option like number of executors,no of cores,executor memory etc.

Could you please advise what would be the optimal value for these parameters for better performance in my case.

Any help would be very much appreciated since it would be helpful for anyone who starts with Spark :)

Thanks.!!

Comment: Regarding optimal values, Its a subjective thing. Do read this two part article  - https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Query1: YARN is a better resource manager and supports more features than Spark Master. For more you can visit
[Apache Spark Cluster Managers](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZptXQ0NDTAhXLuY8KHR5ZCEYQFgg7MAQ&url=http://www.agildata.com/apache-spark-cluster-managers-yarn-mesos-or-standalone/&usg=AFQjCNFwHwxz4PJP5RbTnmT8tdeRb7ibQQ&sig2=9l63lkx5VHqS44ZS5-tnAA)

Query2: You can only assign resources at the time of job initialization. There are command line flags available. Also, if you don't wish to pass command line flags with spark-submit you can set them when creating spark configuration in the code.
You can see the available flags using
`spark-submit --help`

Fore more information visit [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Electing resources majorly depends on the size of data you want to process and the problem complexity.

Please visit [5 mistakes to avoid while writng spark applications](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP0pTc0tDTAhXKu48KHa8IBDIQFggmMAA&url=https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications&usg=AFQjCNESllBTrh7zqgbGe--wHSHcOn7_0w&sig2=ydeQSUAHzrPrNew3PtV6oA)

Comment: Dear, Thanks for your reply. For Query 2 we found that we have options to set the parameters for cores and memory. But it would be great if you could help me what would be the optimum value in my case for better performance result. We are trying to process 3TB of data.

Comment: So, you want to process 3TB of data with 1TB of RAM. How can you expect performance when you have such large dataset and limited resources.